# Dynamic return type, defined by input argument in Python function

Tags: python

Say I have a function, that accepts a `type` object, and returns some value of this type. Like this:

```
>>> from typing import Any, List
>>> def read(T: type) -> Any:  # can we somehow declare T instead of Any?
...     # generating and returning value of type T
...
>>> read(str)
This is a string
>>> read(int)
13
>>> read(List[float])
[1.2, 3.4]
```

etc. (please note, that it is not limited to primitive types like `int`, `str`, `list` etc. but also works with objects of specific classes and more).

Is it possible to specify a concrete dynamic return type (instead of `Any`)? So that, for example, instead of `s: str = read(str)` I could write `s = read(str)`, and my IDE would type-hint `s` as a string?

P.S. In my case, the IDE is JetBrains PyCharm, but would be nice to have a "general" solution. Any Python versions and modules are welcome.

Comment: I think you're looking for [generic types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types).

Comment: There's no actual way to *implement* a function that takes an arbitrary type and returns an instance of that type.

Comment: Well, I've implemented one (good enough for my needs)

Comment: You can look at `read` as a function, that returns value of one of a few dozens types/classes, that I need for my purposes. But I don't want to specify them all in return type declaration, since I (but not my IDE) know concrete type, that will be returned (and it is the function's argument)

Answer (score 1):

Solution, inspired by [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comment:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def read(t: Type[T]) -> T: ...
```